# Python Virtual Environment in Azure Release Pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, virtualenv, alembic

I am using Alembic as mean to perform my database migrations and upgrades. I whish that this migration step would be done by my Azure Release Pipeline to run this basic script:

```
CALL activate ./venv
cd alembic
alembic upgrade head
```

My issue is that I am missing knowledge on how I should make my python virtual env available within my azure release pipeline. I am creating my virtual env within my azure build pipeline already, but this it is not published as an artifact to be used by the release pipeline as it is pretty heavy (around 300 Mb)

I guess creating again the venv from scratch within the release pipeline is not efficient. I am wondering if I am not missing a complete area which would be in charge of properly handling python virtual environments within azure pipelines (build and release).

Thanks